# How can avoid the use of ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder, angular2-ngmodel

I've been stuck on something for hours and I need some help. I'm pretty new to angular.
I'm working with the reactive forms, showing my code and explaining what I want to accomplish.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="filterCate"
    placeholder="Cate" type="search" aria-label="Search" 
    formControlName="pro_cate_id"
    name="search" (focus)="getControl($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let cate of categorias" [value]="cate.id">{{cate.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <button mat-button *ngIf="filterCate" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
    (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); deleteField('pro_cate_id')">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

I have a ng-if where a button is shown to reset the field, and I only need it to be shown when there is a value in the field.  I get the error ***"Property 'filterCate' does not exist on type 'xxxComponent'"***
I know that with the two-way I need that value to exist in the component, if I create the variable there is no problem. But I have about 20 more fields and I don't seem to create 20 variables for all the fields. What could I do in this case, how could I refactor this code without the ng-model in all of the mat-form-field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using reactive forms with the `formControlName` directive, you do not need to use `ngModel` at all, so you can remove that from the `mat-select`.

Now to get the value of your form control `pro_cate_id`, you need to reference its form group. Presumably in your html you have something like:

```html
<element [formGroup]="form">
  ...
  <mat-form-field>
    ...
  </mat-form-field>
</element>
```

So then `form.controls['pro_cate_id'].value` would give you the value of the `mat-select` control, and you can use it like this:

```html
<button *ngIf="form.controls['pro_cate_id'].value"></button>
```

Also, you could disable the button rather than remove it entirely if you want:

```html
<button [disabled]="!form.controls['pro_cate_id'].value"></button>
```

Comment: This is practically what I was looking for! Also in console I had the warning message of ng-model and formControl, now I understand more why it will be deprecated. For now, this is the solution that works for me, I really appreciate it. 
And what makes my function is just reset the field, it is not removing it completely.

`
   deleteField(control_name:any){
    this.form.controls[control_name].reset();
  } 
`

Answer (score 0):

usually when using angular reactive forms you already have the binding of the control with the data when you write on each field the `formControlName="xxxx"` so you already have an access to the field value.
If you still want to use the `[(ngModel)]` with the `<mat-select>` you can wrap it around with another `*ngIf="filterCate"` so the `[(ngModel)]` won't render until this property exists.

Comment: I didn't know I had access to value without using the ng-model, maybe I didn't fully understand how it worked. I appreciate the answer, it serves me well as a guide